# Conexão banco de Dados JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, tomcat

Olá, pessoal.
Meu problema é o seguinte : 
Tenho um projeto JSP, o qual utilizava o banco de dados Oracle SQL. Porém, veio a calhar que eu usasse o MySQL e instalei o .jar do MySQL e alterei a classe de Conexão, tudo certinho, tanto que na classe que testo a DAO vai tudo certinho.
O problema é quando carrego a página no TomCat. Me vêm esses erros:

> type Exception report message Servlet execution threw an exception
>   description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request. exception
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
>     lojavalemobi.util.ConexaoBD.conecta(ConexaoBD.java:25)
>     lojavalemobi.DAO.ProdutoDAO.registrarItem(ProdutoDAO.java:33)
>     br.com.plataforma.controller.ProdutoControle.doPost(ProdutoControle.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
>     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
>     lojavalemobi.util.ConexaoBD.conecta(ConexaoBD.java:25)
>     lojavalemobi.DAO.ProdutoDAO.registrarItem(ProdutoDAO.java:33)
>     br.com.plataforma.controller.ProdutoControle.doPost(ProdutoControle.java:51)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache
>   Tomcat/7.0.81 logs.

O que será que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Já tentou reiniciar tem TomCat?

Comment: O serviço? vou tentar...

Comment: Isso, o serviço

Comment: Eu tinha colocado manualmente. No entanto, eu startei e reiniciei pra testar, e não funcionou. Pelo que estou entendendo é problema com socket, já vi uma vez, mas agora esqueci...

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi, o problema era que não tinha puxado o .jar pra pasta lib e dado build path... erro bobo, mas que custou tempo

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver `